# FileDialog does not display when choosing "Add External JARs..." w/ log exception

Tags: exception, osx-yosemite, eclipse-juno, buildpath

I have `Eclipse Juno` installed on my new MacBook Air Yosemite.  I have imported a project I was working on in my old Mac and I need to add a reference to a new Jar.  Trouble is, **nothing happens** when I click on the Add External JARs!

[image]

Eclipse is up-to-date.  It appears it's just broken and may have something to do with Yosemite - I created a new project and cannot add any external JARs in that project either.

There is a work-around by putting the jars directly into the project's lib folder.  But, this creates duplicate file system objects.

Please advise

This is the entry in Eclipse error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-02-11 11:41:21.303
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.panel_shouldShowFilename(FileDialog.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.dialogProc(Display.java:5410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSSavePanel.setAccessoryView(NSSavePanel.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open(FileDialog.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.BuildPathDialogAccess.chooseExternalJAREntries(BuildPathDialogAccess.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.openExtJarFileDialog(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.libaryPageCustomButtonPressed(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.access$0(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage$LibrariesAdapter.customButtonPressed(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.buttonPressed(TreeListDialogField.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.doButtonSelected(TreeListDialogField.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.access$2(TreeListDialogField.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField$2.widgetSelected(TreeListDialogField.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3658)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. Looks like a weird bug somewhere. Restarting Eclipse worked for me.

Comment: That fixes the issue once per session for me too.  Access it again and the issue re-emerges - forcing another restart of Eclipse to regain the feature.  More than a little inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Eclipse fixes the issue.

Comment: Eclipse is up to date.

Comment: Strange, I was having the same issue, hence the bounty, but it stopped when I updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue with Juno on Yosemite. See the following 
[eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433486), which might be cause of the issue. You might have to switch to latest Eclipse, or at least to the version which contains the fix.

Comment: I think that's a different issue, the stack trace exceptions start on different lines (348 and 360).  That's doesn't mean they are related, but I don't think they are the exact same.